# Insert/delete distance between lists

Tags: python, algorithm, list

Given two lists of 1s and 0s called A and B of the same length, I want to determine if there is some way of inserting exactly n 1s or 0s into A and exactly n 1s or 0s into B to make them the same list.  n will always be less than the lengths of the lists.

For example, set n = 2.  Let `A = [0,0,1,1,0,0]` and `B = [0,1,0,1,0,1]`. We can transform A into `[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0]` by inserting a 1 and a 0. B can be made into the same list by add two 0s at the right hand end.

Is there a known way to compute such a function

```
def match(A,B,n):
    return True if A and B are exactly insertion distance n from a common list
```

?

Comment: One quick observation: if some `n` satisfies the condition, then all `m > n` also satisfy it.

Comment: @Rob What about [] and [0], a distance of 1 is obvious but a distance of 2 is impossible.

Comment: @Veedrac - No, a distance of 1 is impossible, also. We have to add the same number of elements to both lists.

Comment: Ah, I misread the meaning of distance. AOK. Should be quite easy then.

Comment: Another observation: Any two lists of length `n` can be made equal in `n` steps. Trivially: `A' = A + B; B' = A + B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Algorithm

You can solve this by modifying a [standard edit distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to find the minimum number of insertions (x) to make the two strings the same.

Your problem is soluble if and only if x<=2*n.

Python code:

```
A = [0,0,1,1,0,0]
B = [0,1,0,1,0,1]

def match(A,B,n):
    r = len(A)
    if r != len(B):
        return False
    DP = [ [0]*(r+1) for i in range(r+1) ]
    # DP[a][b] is min insertions to A to turn A[:a] and B[:b] into the same string
    for b in range(r+1):
        for a in range(r+1):
            if a>0 and b>0:
                best = DP[a-1][b-1]
                if A[a-1]!=B[b-1]:
                    best += 2 # inserting into both
            elif a==0 and b==0:
                best = 0
            else:
                best = 2*n+1

            if a>0:
                best = min(best,1+DP[a-1][b]) # inserting into A
            if b>0:
                best = min(best,1+DP[a][b-1]) # inserting into B
            DP[a][b] = best
    x = DP[r][r] # we have needed to make x insertions to get A and B to match
    # A and B are now the same length, so we must have made x/2 insertions to each
    return x<=2*n

print match(A,B,2)
```

### Explanation

In your case, you needed to add a 1 and a 0 to A, and two 0's to B so x (the total number of insertions) would be 4.

Note that you may be worried that the algorithm will not give an equal number of insertions to the two strings.  For example, it might find a solution adding 3 characters to A, and 1 to B.  However, this cannot be a solution because then the strings would become different lengths.

If it turns out that x is smaller than 2*n, you can simply pad both strings with the same character until you manage to add exactly n characters to each string.